# Creating dynamically filtered layers using Tilestache/Mapnik?

Tags: mapnik, tilestache, utfgrid

I'm using Tilestache to generate two layers with the `mapnik` and `mapnik grid` providers, and it's working great!

However, I want users to be able to filter the data over many (more than ten) dimensions, and only show the features that match the user's filters. Creating a `mapnik` and `mapnik grid` layer for each of these dimensions--and each new one that comes up--seems like the wrong way to do this. And there are too many features to simply use GeoJSON.

Is there a way to do this filtering dynamically?

Intuitively, I'd like to pass parameters via GET request to Tilestache, which then passes the parameters along to the layers' providers, which tweak their queries.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @ParoX no, I mostly use multiple Tilestache layers or CartoDB for this kinda situation now.

Comment: I am working on the same problem now and I have just stumbled across this link that might be helpful to you if you still want to create such a solution. [TileStache patch #166 on Github](https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/pull/166)