# Mapbox multiple filters to layers

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm new to Mapbox GL and want to understand how i would go about the following;

I have 5 principle layers (from the same source, all vector tiles from Geoserver) which will only be drawn in isolation (ie if one is on the others are off).

Within any of those 5 layers are properties which i want to use as a filter, those properties can apply to any layer. As example below, one property is used to colour polygon (building) I would like to then do something like show only pink buildings with property x OR show any colour building where property x is present.

[image]

In GIS terms this is like running a filter within a layer and providing check boxes for the values within a property.

In total i will have 5 primary layers to which 31 different filters could be applied (filters could be multi - choice -any or only).

Something similar to this [request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59136/creating-dynamically-filtered-layers-using-tilestache-mapnik) on another platform.